# Unable to read properly a text file in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, readfile

I have a txt file which has 2000 row and 10 columns, columns data separated by tab. To read file I simply  defined a function.

```
def readinfo(path):
    info = tf.read_file(path)
return info
```

and when I am trying to read the file

```
path = os.path.join(datadirectory,'1_test','2015.09.13')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
x = readdata.readinfo(path)
sess.run(x)
print(sess.run(tf.shape(x)))
```

but the output is empty `[]`

some posts say we have to use sess.run to load, so, I tried with out using a function

```
path = os.path.join(datadirectory,'1st_test','2003.10.22.12.09.13')
sess = tf.Session()
x = tf.read_file(path)
print(sess.run(x))
```

I get out put as in single line(It is reading the tab and next line also)

```
...0.127\t3.145\t-0.015\t\n1.34\t....
```

where I expect to be in size of [2000x10], which is not loaded correctly.

I need to load the file inside a function because I need to do some mathematical calculations on the column data. How to load file inside a function ? So that I will be able to call the function.

I can do it using

```
def readinfo(path):
    x = numpy.loadtxt(path)
    # loading x in to tensor
    xtensor = tf.constant(x,tf.float32)
    return xtensor
```

I hope this isn't the right way to load in to tensor

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You could just read the file using NumPy and feed its content to TensorFlow

Answer (score 0):

`sess.run(tf.shape(x))` returns the shape of x, not the value of x. The content of a file is a scalar string, so its shape is `[]`, as expected. `sess.run(x)` OTOH should give you the string value.